# Where do I hash the password?

Tags: php, password-encryption

I'm using MVC and I want to know at which point do I hash the user password:

1. before sending to the server (view)
2. in the server, when I set the object field (model)
3. in the server, when I send the object to the controller (controller)
4. in the server, when I prepare the statements (controller)
5. in the database,

e.g. using `"set password = sha256(:password)"` in the statement

I'm kind of confused, I've been always hashing the password when I create the object and set the field "password" but I've read somewhere it's not safe enough. I'm not sure.

Comment: I think you should hash the password on the server side, before writing it to the db. If you hash the password on the client, someone can just go in and remove the hashing function, which will store the password in plain text in the database, which will probably break your authentication (since it'll probably expect a hash)

Comment: Actually the reason you don't hash on the client side is because the hash (for all intents and purposes) then becomes the password, which therefore means that all the "passwords" are then stored in plain text.

Comment: It should be hashed just before writing it to the database; and you should use a password hash algorithm, such as scrypt / bcrypt.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, if I am to handle the password, I will do it server-side. Isn't it safer to hash it before handling it on the server, like I said, right when I create the object? If not, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In the view: This is too high up. There will almost certainly be multiple views in your application which do things with passwords (two simple ones: login form and password change form), and having password hashing in the view would lead to duplication.
- In the database: Too low down. The database should never see plaintext passwords; doing this could, in some situations, end up sending plaintext passwords over the network, displaying them in error messages, or writing them to database logs. Moreover, most of the hash functions supported by databases are too fast to be secure for password storage.
- In the model: Just right. I'd recommend implementing methods on the user object resembling:

  ```
  $user->setPassword($password)    # sets password to specified value
  $user->passwordEquals($password) # returns true if value passed in matches the password
  ```

  Note that none of these methods ever expose the password, or how it's stored -- that's all an implementation detail of the object.

Comment: To add to the second point, the plain text could also be passed back to the user and/or logs if an error occurs with the query.

Comment: Actually, even worse -- they may end up written to database server query logs.

Comment: How is it possible to bcrypt a password, THEN have a function to compare the user-entered password with the database password, like on a password change form? It says it is not recommended to store the salt.

Comment: @ranisalt you have to store the salt. The salt is stored right in the hash. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php. Whoever recommended not storing the salt is probably `md5`ing their passwords and should probably be ignored.

Comment: @ranisalt: That situation shouldn't arise -- the only code that hashes the password should be the user object. If you're hashing the password before you try to compare it, you're doing it too early.

Comment: @ranisalt, If one of these answers has answered your question, please select it by clicking on the check mark beside the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hash it on the server, as soon as you can. ie. as soon as you receive the request from the client. You have no business with the original password, really. Store the hash, and forget it.

As a rule of thumb, you should treat passwords or hashes of passwords as hot potatoes: You want to stop handling them as soon as possible.

Also, on the off chance that the server process is compromised, you don't want sensitive information lurking in the memory of your server. That's why you should avoid letting the original password linger in the memory for too long.

Comment: Interesting concept. I never thought about it, but it probably wouldn't be bad practice to call `unset([$_POST['password'])` right after it's hashed too.

Answer (score 1):

In the [domain object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) that represents to logic use `User` entity. That's within model layer.

Also, SHA256 should not be considered good enough. Should should be using [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). Preferably with `crypt()` function.

Answer (score 0):

First get the value in that field. Then apply the `hash` function. Do the above operations in your controller and then call the model to store in the database. It will give you a better understanding.

(I'm not an expert... pleasure to share my information.. :)

Comment: That's not really a useful answer -- it's far too vague.

Comment: why did you do that?iam just sharing my knowledge..allready i say that iam not an expert.. thanks